# Assing parameter to SQL Bindings located inside the JSON post on Azure Functions

Tags: azure-functions

I am trying to embeed a parameter on my SQL Bindings and the value is on the JSON.
SQL Is not allowing me. It throw me this error: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Unable to resolve binding parameter 'data'. Binding expressions must map to either a value provided by the trigger or a property of the value the trigger is bound to, or must be a system binding expression (e.g. sys.randguid, sys.utcnow, etc.).

```
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
                [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "v1/myApp/{cliented:Guid}/{eventId:Guid}")] HttpRequest req,
                Guid clientId, Guid eventId,
                [Sql("select count(*) as cnt from Somehwere where  " +
                    "        events_Id=@eid and events_cliente_id=@cid and email=@email",
                    CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text,
                    Parameters ="@eid={eventId},@cid={clientId},@email={data.email}",
                    ConnectionStringSetting = "ConnectionStrings:MSSQLConnectionString")] IEnumerable<ContagemEmails> cntEmails,
                ILogger log)
        {
            var receivedContent = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            MyModel data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModel>(receivedContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to bind my sql input to the post data this way :

```
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
                [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post")] HttpRequest req,
                string input,
                [Sql("select count(*) as cnt from Somehwere where  " +
                    "        events_Id=@eid and events_cliente_id=@cid and email=@email",
                    CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text,
                    Parameters ="@eid={eventId},@cid={clientId},@email={data.email}",
                    ConnectionStringSetting = "ConnectionStrings:MSSQLConnectionString")] IEnumerable<ContagemEmails> cntEmails,
                ILogger log)
        {
            var receivedContent = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            MyModel data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModel>(receivedContent);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).